# Reading package lists in update apt-get Ubuntu 12.04 VPS

Tags: updates, package-management, vps

I have VPS and I try to install some packages but I can't, when I try to update my package list, I get an error.

I'm using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

At the end of all process display:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
```

I can't install anything, I try to clean,

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

I try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* -rf
```

And then try to update but all time return the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question when I was researching the same issue that appeared out of nowhere in my Amazon free tier EC2 AMI I use as a web server.

To help fix this, I started this thread:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2140944

As detailed in my solution (3rd post in thread), I got apt to work again by:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

I hope this works for you, too!